# Static labels on rotating arrows in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

## Update after answer:

- After employing the very helpful answer below, my animation now looks like this, and all labels are "glued" in place. Thank you very much!*
  [image]

## Original question:

I have the following rotating animation:
[image: fubar arrow labels]

As you can see, the labels are behaving strange, especially the red ones and the 35 degree angle label. Is it possible to attach the label to a fixed point relative to the arrow head which does not change when rotating the arrow?

My whole code is here, and the labels in question are at line 239, 257 and 280.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Required for \varPsi below
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}

\begin{document}
\foreach \angle in {1,2,...,3}{ %Create all the frames with different angle  (DEFAULT IS {360,359,...,1} - but that takes about 20min rendering time) 

    \begin{tikzpicture}


    %Definitions - These can be changed to create new figures%
    %===========================================================
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Vmax {8/3}; %Max phase voltage (in cm) (8/3 or 2.667 cm is default as that will create a 4 cm space vector)
    %\def \Vs {4}; %Magnitude of space vector in cm OLD
    \def \Angle {\angle}; %Angle with regards to phase A
    \def \Osv {35}; %Angle of d-axis wrt space vector
    \def \R {2.5}; %Magnitude of rotor flux in cm



    %Calculated variables. These should not be changed unless you know what you are doing%
    %===========================================================
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Vs {\Vmax * 1.5};  %Magnitude of space vector in cm
    \pgfmathsetmacro \MaxLin {\Vs * cos{30}}; %Magnitude before overmodulation
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Qmag {\Vs * sin{\Osv})}; %Magnitude of Q axis
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Dmag {\Vs * cos{\Osv})}; %Magnitude of Q axis
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Marker {\Angle/45)};
    %\pgfmathsetmacro \Vmax {\Vs * 2/3}; %Max phase voltage (OLD)
    \def \Axisheight {\Vmax *3};
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Va {\Vmax * sin{(\Angle+0)}}; %Magnitude of phase A at angle \Angle
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Vb {\Vmax * sin{(\Angle+120)}}; %Magnitude of phase B at angle \Angle
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Vc {\Vmax * sin{(\Angle+240)}}; %Magnitude of phase C at angle \Angle
    \pgfmathsetmacro \Radius {\Vmax}; %Radius of maximum line to line voltage output


    %Locations%
    %===========================================================
    \def \OrigoX {-6 cm}; % If you want to move the circle relative to the wave forms (default -6cm)
    \def \OrigoY {0 cm};
    \def \OrigoYb {-11 cm};
    \def \OrigoYc {-22 cm};
    \coordinate (origo) at (\OrigoX,\OrigoY); %Center of top phasor diagram
    \coordinate (origob) at (\OrigoX,\OrigoYb); %Center of center phasor diagram
    \coordinate (origoc) at (\OrigoX,\OrigoYc); %Center of bottom phasor diagram
    \coordinate (phase_a) at (0:\Va cm); %Tip of phase A
    \coordinate (phase_b) at (120:\Vb cm); %Tip of phase B
    \coordinate (phase_c) at (240:\Vc cm) ; %Tip of phase C
    \coordinate (Y) at (\OrigoX+\Vs cm ,\OrigoY+0); %Where to start the Hexagon


    %Circle background rings%
    %===========================================================
    \node at (origo) [circle,thick,draw=black!80,fill=red!0, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\Vs*2 cm] {}; %Top Circle with radius 128% 
    \node at (origob) [circle,thick,draw=black!80,fill=red!0, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\Vs*2 cm] {}; %Center Circle with radius 128% 
    \node at (origoc) [circle,thick,draw=black!80,fill=red!0, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\Vs*2 cm] {}; %Center Circle with radius 128% 

    %Left axis to top circle
    \draw[<->] (1.95*\OrigoX,-1.1*\Vs cm) -- (1.95*\OrigoX,1.1*\Vs cm) node[anchor=south, distance=0.2cm]{$I$};
    \draw [color=black,dotted](\OrigoX,\Vs cm)--(2*\OrigoX,\Vs cm) node[anchor=east, distance=0.5cm] {$\frac{3}{2}i - 150\%$};
    %\draw [color=red,dotted] (\OrigoX,\MaxLin cm) -- (2*\OrigoX,\MaxLin cm) node[anchor=east, distance=0.5cm] {$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}I_{max} - 115,5\%$};
    \draw [color=black,dotted](\OrigoX,\Vmax cm) -- (2*\OrigoX,\Vmax cm) node[anchor=east] {$i - 100\%$};
    \draw [color=black,dotted](\OrigoX,0 cm) -- (2*\OrigoX,0 cm) node[anchor=east] {$0\%$};


    %Hexagon Framing around phasors%
    %===========================================================
    %\draw[-, color=black!50,thin,dashed] (Y) -- ++(120:\Vs cm) -- ++(180:\Vs cm) -- ++(240:\Vs cm) -- ++(300:\Vs cm) -- ++(360:\Vs cm) -- ++(60:\Vs cm); % Six step hexagon
    %\node at (origo) [circle,draw=red!80, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\MaxLin*2 cm] {}; %Circle with radius 115% 



    %Black guide lines with angle notation
    \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360} {
        \draw[-,color=black,dotted, thin] (origo)  -- ++(\x:\Vs cm) node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\x: $\x^{\circ}$}] {};
    } \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360} {
        \draw[-,color=black,dotted, thin] (origob)  -- ++(\x:\Vs cm) node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\x: $\x^{\circ}$}] {};
    } \foreach \x in {45,90,...,360} {
        \draw[-,color=black,dotted, thin] (origoc)  -- ++(\x:\Vs cm) node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\x: $\x^{\circ}$}] {};
    } 





    %=============================================================================================================
    %Actual three phase phasors%
    %=============================================================================================================

    \node [above, align=center] at (0,4.5) [anchor=south]  {\large Three-phased current meassurement: $i_a$, $i_b$, $i_c$}; %Label overhead figure 1
    \node at (origo) [circle,thick,draw=black!80, inner sep=0pt,minimum size=\Vmax*2 cm] {}; %Circle with radius 100%
    \draw[->,color=red, very thick] (origo)  -- ++(phase_a); %Phase A phasor
    \draw[->,color=blue, very thick] (origo)  -- ++(phase_b); %Phase B phasor
    \draw[->,color=green, very thick] (origo)  -- ++(phase_c); %Phase C phasor

    \draw[color=red,thick,smooth,domain=0:8] plot(\x,{\Vmax * sin(\x*45)}); % Phase A
    \draw[color=blue,thick,,smooth,domain=0:8] plot(\x,{\Vmax * sin((\x*45)+120)}); %Phase B
    \draw[color=green,thick,,smooth,domain=0:8] plot(\x,{\Vmax * sin((\x*45)+240)}); % Phase C

    \draw[color=red,dashed] (\Marker,\Va) -- (-0.3,\Va)  node[anchor=east] {$i_a$};; %A phase line to Y-axis
    \draw[color=blue,dashed] (\Marker,\Vb)-- (-0.3,\Vb)  node[anchor=east] {$i_b$};; %B phase line to Y-axis
    \draw[color=green,dashed] (\Marker,\Vc)-- (-0.3,\Vc)  node[anchor=east] {$i_c$};; %C phase line to Y-axis

    %SPACE VECTOR %
    \draw[->,ultra thick,black] (origo) -- ++($(phase_a) + (phase_b) + (phase_c)$) coordinate(Vstip); %Space vector resultant
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}; % X and Y coordinates of Space vector tip

    %Find space vector angle
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{origo}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Vstip}{center}}
    \let\PhaseBlack\pgfmathresult;

    %Phasor guide lines%
    \draw[-,color=red, dashed] (origo)  -- ++(0:\Vmax cm)  node[anchor=west] {\large $i_a$};
    \draw[-,color=blue, dashed] (origo) -- ++(120:\Vmax cm) node[anchor=south] {\large $i_b$};
    \draw[-,color=green, dashed] (origo)  -- ++(240:\Vmax cm) node[anchor=north] {\large $i_c$};

    \draw[-,color=red, dashed] (origo)  -- ++(0:-\Vmax cm) node[anchor=east] {$-i_a$};
    \draw[-,color=blue, dashed] (origo) -- ++(120:-\Vmax cm)  node[anchor=north] {$-i_b$};
    \draw[-,color=green, dashed] (origo)  -- ++(240:-\Vmax cm) node[anchor=south] {$-i_c$};

    \draw[->,color=blue, thin] (origo) ++(phase_a) -> ++(phase_b); %Resultant help lines
    \draw[->,color=green, thin] (origo) ++(phase_a) ++(phase_b) -> ++(phase_c); %Resultant help lines

    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\Vmax) -- (9,\Vmax) ; %X axis TOP inner
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,-\Vmax) -- (9,-\Vmax) ; %X axis bottom inner


    %% Rotor Flux Vector%
    %\coordinate (rfluxtip) at (\PhaseBlack-\Osv:\R); %Tip of rotor flux
    %\draw[->,color=gray] (origo)  -- ++(rfluxtip)  node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\PhaseBlack-\Osv: $\lambda_r$}] {}; %Rotor Flux Phasor


    %Wave form
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,0) -- (9,0) node[anchor=west] {$\theta$}; %X axis
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,-\Vs) -- (0,\Vs) node[anchor=south] {$i$}; %Y axis
    %\draw[help lines] (0,-\Vs) grid (9 ,\Vs); %Grid


    %X Axis help lines
    \foreach \x in {1, 2,...,8} {
        \draw[color=lightgray] (\x cm,\Vs cm) -- (\x cm,-\Vs cm)  {};
        }
    %X Axis tick marks
    \foreach \x in {1, 2,...,8} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro \tick {\x * 45};
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {\small\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tick}$^{\circ}$};
        }

    %Marker to illustrate angle position over wave forms
    \draw[color=black] (\Marker cm, \Vs cm) -- (\Marker cm, -\Vs cm) node[anchor=north,align=center]{$\Angle^{\circ}$}; 

    %Top and bottom border, extending to circle top and and bottom
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\Vs) -- (9,\Vs) ; %X axis TOP outer
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,-\Vs) -- (9,-\Vs) ; %X axis bottom outer










    %=============================================================================================================
    %Alpha and Beta Phasors
    %=============================================================================================================

    \node [above, align=center] at (0,-6.5) [anchor=south]  {\large Clarke Transformation: $i_\alpha$, $i_\beta$};  %Label overhead figure 2

    %SPACE VECTOR %
    \draw[->,ultra thick,black] (origob) -- ++($(phase_a) + (phase_b) + (phase_c)$) coordinate(Vstipb); %Space vector resultant
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordb}{\YCoordb}; % X and Y coordinates of Space vector tip

    %Find space vector angle
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{origob}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Vstipb}{center}}
    \let\PhaseBlackb\pgfmathresult;

    %Green Axis system rotated to rotor angle
    \draw[-,color=green] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYb-\Vs cm) -- ++(90:2*\Vs cm);
    \draw[-,color=green] (\OrigoX+\Vs cm,\OrigoYb)  -- ++(0:-2*\Vs cm);

    \draw[->,color=violet, thin, dashed] (\OrigoX, \YCoordb) -> (Vstipb); %Beta help Line
    \draw[->,color=orange, thin, dashed] (\XCoordb, \OrigoYb) -> (Vstipb); %Alpha help Line

    \draw[->,color=violet, very thick] (origob)  -- ++(0,\YCoordb-\OrigoYb) node[anchor=north east] {\large $i_\beta$}; %Phase beta phasor
    \draw[->,color=orange, very thick] (origob)  -- ++(\XCoordb-\OrigoX,0) node[anchor=north] {\large $i_\alpha$}; %Phase alpha phasor

    \coordinate (origobb) at (0,\OrigoYb); %Center of center phasor diagram
    \draw[color=violet,thick,smooth,domain=0:8, shift=(origobb)]  plot(\x,{\Vs * sin((\x*45)+90)}); % Beta wave form
    \draw[color=orange,thick,smooth,domain=0:8, shift=(origobb)]  plot(\x,{\Vs * sin((\x*45)+0)}); % Alpha wave form

    \draw[color=violet,dashed] (\Marker,\YCoordb)-- (-0.3,\YCoordb)  node[anchor=east] {$i_\beta$};; %Beta line to beta-axis
    \draw[color=orange,dashed] (\Marker,\XCoordb-\OrigoX+\OrigoYb)-- (-0.3,\XCoordb-\OrigoX+\OrigoYb)  node[anchor=east] {$i_\alpha$};; %Alpha line to alpha-axis

    %Wave form
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,\OrigoYb) -- (9,\OrigoYb) node[anchor=west] {$\theta$}; %X axis middle
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,\OrigoYb-\Vs cm) -- (0,\OrigoYb+\Vs cm) node[anchor=south] {$i$}; %Y axis middle
    \draw[help lines] (0,\OrigoYb-\Vs cm) grid (9 ,\OrigoYb+\Vs cm); %Grid middle

    %X Axis tick marks
    \foreach \x in {1, 2,...,8} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro \tick {\x * 45};
        \draw (\x cm,\OrigoYb-1pt) -- (\x cm,\OrigoYb+1pt) node[anchor=north] {\small\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tick}$^{\circ}$};
        }

    %Marker to illustrate angle position over wave forms
    \draw[color=black] (\Marker cm,\OrigoYb+\Vs cm) -- (\Marker cm, \OrigoYb-\Vs cm) node[anchor=north,align=center]{ $\Angle^{\circ}$}; 

    %Top and bottom border, extending to circle top and and bottom
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYb+\Vs cm) -- (9,\OrigoYb+\Vs cm) ; %X axis TOP outer
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYb-\Vs cm) -- (9,\OrigoYb-\Vs cm) ; %X axis bottom outer









    %=============================================================================================================
    %%D and Q Phasors%
    %=============================================================================================================

    \node [above, align=center] at (0,-17.5) [anchor=south]  {\large Park Transformation: $i_d$, $i_q$};    %Label overhead figure 3

    %Space Vector
    \draw[->,ultra thick,black] (origoc) -- ++($(phase_a) + (phase_b) + (phase_c)$) node[label={[label distance=0.1 cm,,rotate=\PhaseBlackb-90, color=red]\PhaseBlackb-90: $\lambda_{stator}$}] {} coordinate(Vstipc); %Space vector resultant
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoordc}{\YCoordc}; % X and Y coordinates of Space vector tip

    %Find space vector angle
    \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{origoc}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{Vstipc}{center}}
    \let\PhaseBlackc\pgfmathresult;

    \coordinate (d1c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:\Vs cm) ; %Tip of d axis
    \coordinate (d2c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:-\Vs cm) ; %Tip of d axis
    \coordinate (q1c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv+90:\Vs cm) ; %Tip of q axis
    \coordinate (q2c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv+90:-\Vs cm) ; %Tip of q axis

    \coordinate (d3c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv+90:\Qmag) ; %Tip of d 
    \coordinate (q3c) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:\Dmag) ; %Tip of q 

    \draw[->,color=orange, thin, dashed] (origoc)  -- ++(d3c) -> (Vstipc); %Q help Line
    \draw[->,color=violet, thin, dashed] (origoc)  -- ++(q3c) -> (Vstipc); %Q help Line

    \draw[->,color=green, thick] (origoc)  -- ++(d1c) node[label={[label distance=0.1 cm,rotate=\PhaseBlackc-\Osv-90, color=red]\PhaseBlackc-\Osv-90: $\lambda_{rotor}$}] {}; %D axis help line
    \draw[-,color=green, thin] (origoc)  -- ++(d2c); %D axis help line
    \draw[-,color=green, thick] (origoc)  -- ++(q1c); %Q axis help line
    \draw[-,color=green, thin] (origoc)  -- ++(q2c); %Q axis help line

    \draw[->,color=orange, very thick] (origoc)  -- ++(d3c) node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\PhaseBlackc-\Osv+90:\large $i_q$}] {}; %q phasor
    \draw[->,color=violet, very thick] (origoc)  -- ++(q3c) node[label={[label distance=-0.18cm]\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:\large $i_d$}] {}; %d phasor

    \coordinate (origocc) at (0,\OrigoYc); %Center of center phasor diagram
    \draw[color=orange,thick,,smooth,domain=0:8, shift=(origocc)] plot(\x,{\Qmag}); % Q
    \draw[color=violet,thick,,smooth,domain=0:8, shift=(origocc)] plot(\x,{\Dmag}); % D

    \draw[color=orange,dashed] (0,\OrigoYc+\Qmag cm)-- (-0.3,\OrigoYc+\Qmag cm)  node[anchor=east] {$i_q$}; %d line to y axis
    \draw[color=violet,dashed] (0,\OrigoYc+\Dmag cm)-- (-0.3,\OrigoYc+\Dmag cm)  node[anchor=east] {$i_d$}; %q line to y axis

    %% Rotor Flux Vector%
    %\coordinate (rfluxtipc) at (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:\R); %Tip of rotor flux
    %\draw[->,color=yellow, thick] (origoc)  -- ++(rfluxtipc)  node[anchor=west] {$\lambda_r$}; %Bottom Rotor Flux Phasor

    % angular velocity \omega
    \draw[->] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYc) ++(\PhaseBlackc-10:.85*\Vs) arc (\PhaseBlackc-10:\PhaseBlackc+10:.85*\Vs) node[label={[label distance=0.1 cm,rotate=\PhaseBlackc-90]left: $\omega_{m}$}] {};

    % Angle between rotor and stator
    \draw[->, thick] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYc) ++(\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:.35*\Vs) arc (\PhaseBlackc-\Osv:\PhaseBlackc:.35*\Vs) node[label={[label distance=0.0 cm]below: \small $\Osv^{\circ}$}] {};

    %WAVE FORM%
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,\OrigoYc) -- (9,\OrigoYc) node[anchor=west] {$\theta$}; %X axis bottom
    \draw[->, color=black] (0,\OrigoYc-\Vs cm) -- (0,\OrigoYc+\Vs cm) node[anchor=south] {$i$}; %Y axis bottom
    \draw[help lines] (0,\OrigoYc-\Vs cm) grid (9 ,\OrigoYc+\Vs cm); %Grid middle

    %X Axis tick marks
    \foreach \x in {1, 2,...,8} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro \tick {\x * 45};
        \draw (\x cm,\OrigoYc-1pt) -- (\x cm,\OrigoYc+1pt) node[anchor=north] {\small\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tick}$^{\circ}$};
        }

    %Marker to illustrate angle position over wave forms
    \draw[color=black] (\Marker cm,\OrigoYc+\Vs cm) -- (\Marker cm, \OrigoYc-\Vs cm) node[anchor=north,align=center]{$\Angle^{\circ}$}; 

    %Top and bottom border, extending to circle top and and bottom
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYc+\Vs cm) -- (9,\OrigoYc+\Vs cm) ; %X axis TOP outer
    \draw[color=gray] (\OrigoX,\OrigoYc-\Vs cm) -- (9,\OrigoYc-\Vs cm) ; %X axis bottom outer


    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

If you want to create the animation, you should also make this code in a separate file in the same folder: (then the above code should be named "frames2") Also pay attention to the comment on line 17 in the first file. A full 360 degree render takes a lot of time, so I normally render at 4 different angles to check my results while testing (e.g \foreach \angle in {1,90,180,270}.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{animate} 

\begin{document} 
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{72}{frames2}{}{} %Create animation of the output file with all the frames
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples that produce "attached lables", one using `transform shape`, the other using rotation correction.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i in {0,30,..., 330}
    \draw[red, ->, rotate=\i, transform shape] (0,0) -- +(0:3) node[rotate=-90,above]{fixed};
  \foreach \i in {0,30,..., 330}
    \draw[->] (7,0) -- +(\i:3) node[rotate=\i-90,above]{fixed};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]